# log4j2 + composite configuration + web.xml

Tags: configuration, log4j2, web.xml, composite

I have a web app and it has some dependent jars (one of them is a rest client).
My scenario is this.
I have a log4j2-cswc.xml defined in the rest client dependent jar and is supposed to write the logs to a separate rolling file. In the web app, I have a log4j2.xml defined.

Composite configuration says we have to specify the list of separated file paths on log4j.configurationFile system property. In case if I do not want to use the system property, the equivalent of using a context parameter in the web.xml is log4jConfiguration.

Now I tried to declare the log4jConfiguration `context-param` as below.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml,classpath:log4j2-cwsc.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Even though, it shows the below log entry that it is starting the LoggerContext,

```
DEBUG Starting LoggerContext[name=XYZ] from configuration at file:/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml,classpath:log4j2-cwsc.xml
```

it is only loading the log4j2.xml of the web app (as you would notice in the following log) and ignores the rest client dependent log4j2-cwsc.xml following the explanation [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html). My expectation based on the composite configuration is that it would merge both the configurations.

```
DEBUG Starting LoggerContext[name=XYZ, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@9e8a94] with configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/apps/v85/WebSphere/wp_profile/installedApps/node1/PA_XYZ.ear/XYZ-17.0.6-SNAP.war/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml]
```

So what is correct way to declare the composite configuration to include the log4j2 configuration from a dependent jar in a web.xml file? Note: I am using log4j2 v2.8.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Support for CompositeConfigurations in web applications requires that you add log4j-web as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks @rgoers. I believe, I have the log4j-web added in the dependencies already. Anyway, I shall check that.